# duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassName in

Tags: ios, xcode7, ocmock, lcov

I'm using [OCMOCK](http://ocmock.org/ios/) for class mocking and [lcov](http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/09/21/code-coverage-for-ios-xcode-7/) for code coverage. For OCMock to work i have to set `-ObjC` flag under "Other linker flag" and for lcov to generate code coverage for .m file i need to add that file under `TestTarget -> Compile Source` but if i do this its giving me below errors

```
"duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassName in" 

"duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Class Name in"

"duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ClassName._sharedCoAPEngine in:"
```

Is there any work around for this, by which i can use lcov with OCMock??

Comment: This happens when you add import same file twice. Recheck your code.

Comment: Yes! Its linking my file twice one with -ObjC flag for OCMock and other by adding .m file under TestTarget -> Compile Source for lcov code coverage report generation.

Comment: OCMock is available in Cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org/?q=ocmock. To avoid library conflicts & dependencies problem, use Cocoapods